# Missing argument 1 for hook_field_schema()

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a new module that defines a new field type for my Drupal site. When the module installs, I get a warning in the recent log messages that says "Warning: Missing argument 1 for api_token_field_schema() in api_token_field_schema() (line 11 of /sites/all/modules/custom/api_token/api_token.install)." I can't see anything wrong with my schema definition. Any ideas why I would be getting this error? Here is my complete.install file.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Install, update and uninstall functions for the API token module.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function api_token_field_schema($field) {
  $columns = array(
    'apitoken' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 64,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  );

  $indexes = array(
    'apitoken' => array('apitoken'),
  );

  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
    'indexes' => $indexes,
  );
}
```